# How To Create Notification Service For Android Device?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to develop the notification system where from web application when i click on "**Send Notification**" button that will send notification to all the device where my apps installed.

I googled a lot and found few clue how to do it.

1. Cloud google notification.
2. Pull service.

Pull service runs on device all time so it will effect the device performance.

I have totally confused what to do and which option will be best for me?

Please suggest me and if anyone has development please share me if you have demo apps of it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Cloud Messaging Reference](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use GCM - Google cloud messaging for your functionality.

Refer to demo application given in android developer site.

[**GCM Demo Application**](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html)

And main link is - [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that allows you to send data from your server to your users' Android-powered device. This could be a lightweight message telling your app there is new data to be fetched from the server.[For more details](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Android Push Notifications using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), PHP and MySQL.[Click here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/).

Google Cloud Messaging for Android.[Click here](http://www.optimusmobility.com/2012/08/17/google-cloud-messaging-android/)